Object is possibly 'undefined' ts{18048}
I created this program where I need to map data from an api.
There is an error that just says that the 'result' could be undefined.
    import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import { Movie } from "./Movies";

    export default function MoviesList() {
      const [result, setResult] = useState<Movie[]>();
      useEffect(() => {
        LoadMovies();
      }, []);
      async function LoadMovies() {
        const response = await fetch("https://localhost:****/api/movies");
        const movies = await response.json();
        movies.releaseDate = ConvertDate(new Date(movies.releaseDate));
        setResult(movies);
      }
      function ProcessMovie(movie: Movie, id: number) {
        return (
          <tr>
            <td>{movie.title}</td>
            <td>{movie.genre}</td>
            <td>{movie.director}</td>
            <td>{movie.price}</td>
            <td>{movie.revenue}</td>
            <td>{movie.releaseDate}</td>
          </tr>
        );
      }
      function ConvertDate(d: Date) {
        return (
          d.getFullYear +
          ("0" + d.getMonth + 1).slice(-2) +
          ("0" + d.getDate).slice(-2)
        );
      }
      return <table><tbody>{result.map(ProcessMovie)}</tbody></table>
    }


I created a class movies as well.
    export class Movie {
      title: string | undefined;
      director: string | undefined;
      genre: string | undefined;
      price: number | undefined;
      revenue: number | undefined;
      releaseDate: string | undefined;
    }



I have tried some things including taking away the undefined for the movie class properties, but new errors pop up.
What should I do?
Thank you in advance.

you didn't pass an array instance into useState

as @DanielA.White said, the returned api data seems an object rather an array based on your code movies.releaseDate = ConvertDate(new Date(movies.releaseDate));

Another concern is that assume your response returns an array, you can't modify the property value movies.releaseDate directly. You need to iterate each element in the movies array and set the field value.

Issue 1
You are not providing the default/initial value in the useState as mentioned in the comment. So currently your result is a Movie[] | undefined type.
Solution: Provide the empty array to make the result as Movie[] type.
const [result, setResult] = useState<Movie[]>([]);

Issue 2
Assume that the response returned is an array, you can't directly modify property value with movies.releaseDate. Instead, you need to iterate each element and update its releaseDate field. Also, you should declare the movies variable with let instead of const as the const keyword will not allow re-assign the variable.
Solution:
const response = await fetch('https://localhost:****/api/movies');
let movies = await response.json();

movies = movies.map((x) => ({
  ...x,
  releaseDate: ConvertDate(new Date(x.releaseDate)),
}));

Issue 3
You are not calling the Date functions. This will result in the generated date incorrectly.
Solution:
function ConvertDate(d: Date) {
  return (
    d.getFullYear() +
    ('0' + d.getMonth() + 1).slice(-2) +
    ('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2)
  );
}

Demo @ StackBlitz

Also, you should declare the movies variable with let instead of const as the const keyword will not allow re-assign the variable. this is not always right. for primitive variable like string, number, boolean etc is true. but for reference variable like object, array we still can modify the property/element of the variable.

Thank you, I tried it and it fixed the bug.
